# How to add picture subfolders in Pelican

Tags: pelican

In the content/images folder, when I place my images in the subfolder of images, the images couldn't be showed. 
The file structure is:

```
 content->images->1.jpg
        ->images->travel->2.jpg
        ->diary->this file.md
```

In this file.md, I insert the picture by:

```
  ![mypic](../images/1.jpg)
  ![mypic2](../images/travel/2.jpg)
```

2.jpg can not be showed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problem is solved by using absolute links instead of relative links.

To do this, we should get the picture link in the github space then insert it into the 'md' file by

```
![imags](https://github.com/****/***.github.io/blob/master/imgs/travel/1.JPG?raw=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your post it is looking for your picture at `images/travel/1.jpg` but it is really located at `images/travel/2.jpg`.

Try replacing

```
![mypic2](images/travel/1.jpg)
```

With

```
![mypic2](images/travel/2.jpg)
```

Comment: Can you show all of the code? Otherwise I can not help. Try replacing [mypic2] with [mypic] on the last line

Comment: Thanks, I have rewritten the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Per [Linking to static files](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#linking-to-static-files), in the Pelican docs, you should include `{filename}` in the links as follows:

```
![mypic]({filename}/images/1.jpg)
![mypic2]({filename}/images/travel/2.jpg)
```

Comment: @hunter could you offer more detail? Are the image files being processed into the output directory? What src URL is ending up in the HTML? What configuration do you have relating to static files?

Comment: Thanks for your advise, after checking the files in the output directory, I found the src is not correct.  And modification make it correctly show on my local computer, but still fail after uploading to github pages.

Comment: @hunter why have you put relative links? What happened when you used {filename} as I and the docs tell you to? Can you show the relevant config, input and output? Otherwise I'm just guessing b

Comment: I just solved this problem by using absolute links. It seems that the relative links can't be parsed correctly.